# How to share Azure Function logs with 3rd party

Tags: azure, logging, azure-storage, azure-functions

I have some Azure Functions that I share to my partner companies who then run the Azure Functions in their own Azure subscriptions.

Occasionally the partners run into issues and reach out to me for help. I have to instruct them to manually pull the Azure Function logs and send to me via email.

Is there anyway they can grant me permission to pull the logs from their Azure Subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on where you have the logs.

Either way, they can grant you RBAC permission to their resource in their subscription. Generally, they have read only access options available. All resources have the same experience for modifying RBAC (but they do differ on which policies they support). It's pretty straightforward, but this doc has more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure

If you're using our default Storage logs, do yourself a favor and turn on App Insights because it's great. Then, if you still want to use Storage, you can get RBAC access or a SAS token and grab those logs from the Storage Account associated with the Function App. (Name should be in the AzureWebJobsDashboard setting). If you get a SAS token, you can use the Storage Explorer by choosing the SAS URI option when you connect.

[image: Storage Explorer Connection UI with SAS URI selected]

If you're using App Insights, good job, you've made the right decision. You can get RBAC access to the App Insights resource and use all their great UI experience/etc. You can also get an API Key and make direct API calls against it, in the case that RBAC wouldn't work. (I would try to get RBAC access, but if that's not possible, here's a link to App Insights REST API docs: https://dev.applicationinsights.io/quickstart)

Short answer, use RBAC to get granted limited permissions (and App Insights because it's great)

Comment: I am trying to add a 'reader' role to my resource group from 'Access Control (IAM)' page but running into issues when the user is from a different AAD tenant.

I have selected add role button and set the following fields. 
role: reader
assign access to: Azure AD user, group, or application
select: <email here>

when I type in the email of an AAD user in a different tenant, the user is not found and I cannot grant them read role.

Are there any additional steps to allow someone from a different AAD tenant access to my resource group?

Comment: Ah, yeah. Not super sure since I've not done it myself. There's a doc here about adding a O365 tenant to an existing sub. You can also create a vendor account in your AD or just use a Microsoft account (@outlook.com email) if you want to avoid adding another tenant. Vendor account would be my preference on my experience since I wouldn't want another tenant mucking around in my sub.